# alternating relative prime gap series

Tags: limits, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let $p(n)$ be the $n$th prime, $g(n) = p(n+1) - p(n)$ be the $n$th prime gap, and $r(n) = g(n) / p(n)$ be the $n$th relative prime gap. The Prime Number Theorem implies that $r \rightarrow 0$.

Consider the series $$\sum_n (-1)^n r(n).$$ This is an alternating series with terms going to 0, albeit not monotonically. Morally (assuming no conspiracy of primes) and computationally it seems this sum converges to 0. Is it known whether this series does indeed converge and if so, whether the limit is 0?

Comment: For the convergence, summing by parts it means estimating $\sum_{m=1}^{n} (-1)^mg(m)$. Assuming it is close to $\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} g(m)-g(m+1) = -g(n)$ we need to show the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{g(n)^2}{p(n)^2}$

Comment: @user1952009 How do you get summation by parts to work? $r(n)$ is not of the form $s(n+1) - s(n)$ as far as I can see.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^n g(n)}{p(n)} =  \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^n g(n)}{p(N)}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (\sum_{m=1}^n(-1)^m g(m))(\frac1{p(n)}-\frac{1}{p(n+1)})$